# Comparar 2 tablas para después insertar los datos que no estén repetidos

Tags: sql

Buen día
Estoy trabajando con el bulk insert  de sql y me funciona perfecto

El resultado del bulk insert lo guardo en una Tabla temporal

Lo que quiero hacer es comparar los datos de esa tabla temporal con otra tabla que tengo y solo insertar los datos nuevos en la tabla fisica

Este es mi query

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE SPI_Archivos 
@filePath varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  SET LANGUAGE Spanish;

  CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    Cuenta nvarchar(max),
    Nombre nvarchar(max),
    Monto float,
    Fecha date,
    Clasificación nvarchar(max)
  )

  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) = 'BULK INSERT #TempTable FROM ''' + @filePath + ''' WITH (FIRSTROW=2, ROWTERMINATOR =''' + CHAR(10) + ''' )';
  EXEC (@sql);

  Insert INTO Balanzas 
  SELECT * from #TempTable te WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from Balanzas b where te.Nombre= b.Nombre)
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Balanzas b where te.Monto = b.Monto)
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Balanzas b where te.Fecha = b.Fecha)
  And NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Balanzas b where te.Clasificación = b.Clasificación)

END
```

ojo: en la tabla física ya tengo datos registrados por eso la comparación

estas son las 2 tablas :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar gracias:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas **SQL Server** puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Atendiendo lo que dices, lo que deseas es obtener **los registros de la tabla temporal que no existen en la tabla balanzas**, para resolver esto debes aplicar la operación de resta de conjuntos. Este operador en **SQL Server** se llama **Except** y en **Oracle** seria **Minus**.

```
select cuenta, nombre, monto, fecha, clasificacion, campoN
from TempTable
except
select cuenta, nombre, monto, fecha, clasificacion, campoN
from Balanzas
```

Para que este operador funcione ambas consultas deben tener en la **cláusula select** la misma cantidad de campos y ser del mismo tipo esos campos.

Aquí seleccionamos todos los registros de la **tabla TempTable** que están en la propia **tabla TempTable** pero no existen en la **tabla Balanzas**.

Entonces para hacer la operación de inserción de estos registros obtenidos deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
insert into Balanzas
select * from
(select cuenta, nombre, monto, fecha, clasificacion, campoN
 from TempTable
 except
 select cuenta, nombre, monto, fecha, clasificacion, campoN
 from Balanzas)
```

Insertamos en la **tabla Balanzas** los registros obtenidos con la consulta antes explicada.

Existen además otros operadores de conjunto tales como la **unión** y la **intersección**, te recomiendo que investigues más sobre los conjuntos y las operaciones que se pueden realizar con estos, ya que son fundamentales para el trabajo con base de datos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Japv si me funciono ,Gracias